# Obj C call to Cocos2dx C++ non-static function

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, in-app-purchase, cocos2d-x

I'm writing code for in app purchase in iOS on my cocos2dx game. I want to call my C++ function from Obj C. I can call C++ static function by using *.mm implementation file Obj-C++. But I want to update user interface while the purchasing progress. I've tried to create a singleton class, but the Obj-C still not recognize the function from the singleton object.

**C++ : SceneAcc.cpp**

```
void SceneAcc::stateChecker()
{
    if(BridgeObjCpp::sharedBridge()->isPurchasing == false)
   {
       this->unschedule(schedule_selector(SceneAcc::stateChecker));
       removeBuyCash();
   }
}

// There is an update scheduler to check if the purchase phase done
```

**C++ : BridgeObjCpp.mm**

```
BridgeObjCpp* BridgeObjCpp::sharedBridge(){
    if (! s_bridge) {
        s_bridge = new BridgeObjCpp();
    }
    return s_bridge;
}

// Init singleton object
// And bool isPurchasing property in the header
```

**IAPManager.m**

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"Complete Transaction...");

    // I want something like this
    BridgeObjCpp::sharedBridge()->isPurchase = true;

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];

}
```

Comment: And how does it fail ? Calling `BridgeObjCpp::sharedBridge()->isPurchase = true;` on the `IAPManager.m` should work (though you will have to rename it to .mm or change its type to `Objective-C++ Source`). Try doing that and tell us the compiler error if this does not work

Comment: I'm sorry I can't give the fail report. I get another error while tweaking the code. Now i'm getting "Lexical or Preprocessor Error - CCDataVisitor.h : "string" file not found" :(

Comment: Yes, at that point `CCDataVisitor.h` probably `#include`  some piece that contains pieces of c++ code (such as an `#include <string>`). You would probably be better off compiling your project for objective-C++, add `-x objective-c++` to your compiler flags.

Comment: I got 3 dropdown flag menu : Other C, Other C++ and Other Warning Flags. And Each of them have Debug and Release properties. Which one I should set to -x objective-c++?

Comment: Other C flags should be fine

Comment: @Olotiar the error growing to 8 semantic issue :( I think I have to revert the project into last working build. This Lexical error happens to me before, and I always have to revert to get it working again, even when the last error-generating-code removed

Comment: @Olotiar I changed the Identity and Type panel of the class, to "Objective-C++ Source" and the lexical error gone. Thank you very much olotiar, you saved my day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify either BridgeObjCpp.mm or IAPManager.m.

- Add static methods in BridgeObjCpp.mm to handle static objects and in
  effective BridgeObjCpp.mm will act as wrapper to communicate C++
  methods.

**BridgeObjCpp.h**

```
@interface BridgeObjCpp : NSObject

+(void)setPurchasing:(BOOL)purchasing:

@end
```

**BridgeObjCpp.mm**

```
@implementation BridgeObjCpp

+(void)setPurchasing:(BOOL)purchasing {
  BridgeObjCpp::sharedBridge()->isPurchase = purchasing ;
}

@end
```

**IAPManager.m**

```
[BridgeObjCpp setPurchasing:YES];
```

**OR**

- Rename IAPManager.m to IAPManager.mm to use C++ conventions.

Note: In .mm files compiler expect a mixture of objective C and C++ codes. In .m files it expect only objective C code. So please do the coding respectively.

Comment: I'm getting "Lexical or Preprocessor Error - CCDataVisitor.h : "string" file not found" when I convert the bool isPurchasing to static properties. All I wanted to do is getting a reference of currently running class instance of SceneApp.cpp from Obj-C and call the method to update my UI. Is it possible?

Comment: Edited answer to have a sneak around wrapper implementation.

Comment: Thanks Midhere, it works! I'm using a static variable before to make it simple, but it won't work. And then I use your method to use the variable from singleton object, and working perfectly. :)